# Density of a set of natural numbers relative to another set of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I know what the density of a set of natural numbers is. For example, the density of even numbers is $1/2$, the density of multiples of $4$ is $1/4$, and the density of perfect squares and also the density of perfect cubes are both $0$. However, I am interested in the density of a set $A$ of natural numbers relative to a set $B$ of natural numbers. For example, the density of even numbers relative to itself is $1$, while the density of multiples of $4$ relative to the density of even numbers is $1/2$. Also, the density of perfect squares relative to even numbers is $0$. So, my question is, what is the precise definition of the density of a set $A$ of natural numbers relative to a set $B$ of natural numbers? Note, $A$ does not necessarily have to be a subset of $B$. Also, has there been any papers that define this notion and prove some results?

Comment: It is suspect that you give examples of relative density before you define what it means... What is *your* definition of relative density?

Comment: If you are using $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A \cap \{1, \ldots, n\}}{n}$ for [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), then I suppose you could then use $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A \cap \{1, \ldots, n\}}{B \cap \{1, \ldots, n\}}$ for relative density of $A$ w.r.t. $B$.

Comment: @angryavian It is not clear to me whether the multiples of $3$ have a density relative to multiples of $2$ of $\frac23$ or $\frac13$ (since a third of even numbers are multiples of $3$) with perhaps $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A \cap B\cap\{1, \ldots, n\}|}{|B \cap \{1, \ldots, n\}|}$ if the second version is the one intended

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the correction, I did intend to suggest the definition at the end of your comment.